# Exporting a Sketch Prototype

Tags: sketch-app, prototyping

**Is it possible to export a Sketch prototype as a working file?**

I have made a prototype but I need to export it to show a stakeholder and give to my boss so he can use it in a meeting.

Are there any ways in Sketch, Plugins etc that I'm not aware of?

Im running Sketch 50.2, which is the latest version right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a prototype in sketch you can upload it to Sketch Cloud, which means anyone with the link will be able to see & navigate your prototype. Check out sketch's [documentation on previewing](https://sketchapp.com/docs/prototyping/previewing)

Answer (score 3):

Puzzle Publisher plugin creates clickable HTML.

https://github.com/ingrammicro/puzzle-publisher

Answer (score 2):

I heard of the tool called **Mirr.io**. For more information I'll direct you to this page:

[Mirr.io](https://blog.prototypr.io/mirrio-23949b2e66ad)

*You can preview your prototype in any browser, on any device - LIVE. It has once-click sharing and is totally free with no sign up required.*